# How to always get the attribute label from "default store"?

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, labels

I'm trying to improve an extension. Currently it returns attribute labels from the store that the item was purchased, but I need it to always return the labels from the default store.

This is a generalization of the script they are using to request the attributes, labels. (from what I understand)

```
 $config    = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
$attribute = $config->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $options['options'][$i]['label']);   
$label_ar    = $attribute->getStoreLabels();       
$options['options'][$i]['label'] = $label_ar[$specific_store_id];
```

Could you perhaps make a guess of what I would need to change for it to always return default store attribute labels? 
(I understand that there is not a lot of info to work with, but I don't want to expose too much of the code)